# How to convert a field into timestamp in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

how to convert the forth field into timestamp? I have loaded into a table but while querying it is showing as NULL.

1::1193::5::**978300760**

**my table format :**

```
CREATE TABLE `mv`(
  `uid` INT, 
  `mid` INT, 
  `rating` INT, 
  `tmst` TIMESTAMP)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'='::', 
  'serialization.format'='::') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
```

Now, in the last column tmst, I want to store timestamp in some format but in the input file I have unix timestamp(like - 7367354673). Now my question is whether I have to convert that unix timestamp into readable format and store it into the table as a timestamp or string? Which is best? I tried storing it as a timestamp but while querying it gives NULL value.

Comment: What is your table definition?

Comment: Use `show create table ...`  and add it to your original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1.

You are using the wrong SerDe.
`LazySimpleSerDe` does not support multi-character delimiter.
When you try to use it, only one character is taken in account so your delimiter is practically `:` (and not `::`).
The record `1::1193::5::978300760` is interpreted as following:

```
C     = Column
D     = Delimiter
(E/N) = Empty/Null

C1  D1   C2(E/N) D2 C3    D3  C4(E/N) D4 C5  D5 C6 D6  C7
|   |    |       |  |     |   |       |  |   |  |  |   |
1   :            :  1193  :           :  5   :     :   978300760
```

P.s. Since your table has 4 columns, everything after the 4th field is being ignored

#### 2.

`tmst`(Epoch) should be defined as `bigint`

---

#### MultiDelimitSerDe + BIGINT

```
create external table mv
(
    uid     int
   ,mid     int 
   ,rating  int 
   ,tmst    bigint
)
row format serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe'
with serdeproperties ("field.delim"="::")
stored as textfile
;
```

---

```
select * from mv
;
```

---

```
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
| mv.uid | mv.mid | mv.rating |  mv.tmst  |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|      1 |   1193 |         5 | 978300760 |
+--------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

Comment: Thank u so much :) for clear explanation.
suppose if I want to convert the Epoch into human readable format(say yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) and store it in the table then how should I defind the tmst column and how can I convert this while loading data into the table.

Comment: **MultiDelimitSerDe throws below error**

`FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. Cannot validate serde: org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimSerDe`

Comment: **(1)** This is a tested code. Why are you trying to use `MultiDelimSerDe` when I specifically wrote `MultiDelimitSerDe`? **(2)** You can't convert it without querying it and for that you first have to define a table correctly.

Comment: I gave wrong spelling :(. Now it is working fine. :) thank u so much for replying.

Answer (score 1):

Null output shows when the column value and column data type mismatches.

I guess, you have specified the timestamp column data type as timestamp. If you are not converting it into timestamp format and you want to display in table you must specify the data type as bigint datatype for this column.

If you want to convert use the below syntax.

```
select from_unixtime(978300760,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS") ;
select from_unixtime(columnname,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS") as timestamp;
```

Comment: so while defining timestamp column in a table, how should we do, should we define it as a timestamp or string? what is best ? I have unixtime in a text file and want to convert it to timestamp and store it in a table so that I can use it for querying/joining etc.,

Comment: It always recommended using the corresponding data types for each column. If you have the timestamp value. For example, if your column value looks like this 2017-05-23 18:33:29 then use timestamp data type and 2017-05-23 use Date type if doesn't have time. 

If you define the timestamp column data as String, you can't make filter or query the data further based on Time, year, date, month, etc...
If you define any other type other than String, Timestamp it will show null.

Please upvote if you feel it is useful.

Comment: as of now I only have unix timestamp in file (like 978300760 ) so how do I convert this into timestamp format like yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss and store in table as a timestamp so that it wont show NULL when I query the table.

Comment: Check the answer which I have given above.

Comment: @akm, this does not solve your NULLs issue. If you want to ask an additional question (e.g. "how to convert Epoch into Timestamp?") , open an additional post, although you already have endless posts in that subject in SO.

Comment: `timestamp` is giving me error as an alias, it can be anything else `select from_unixtime(columnname,"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS") as other_than_timestamp;`